# Why is Circle Avatar initially showing blue bg instead of default picture set, flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have side menu in an app in flutter. The circle avatar is supposed to show a default profile picture since user has not set one. When I first install it, it should look like this: [image]

But this is how it looks like when I first install it....[image]

I want it to show default profile photo instead of blue container.
This is the code :

```
GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () async {
                                newphoto = await Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: ((context) => ProfilePage(
                                            uname: context
                                                .read<ProfileDetails>()
                                                .name //username,
                                            ))));

                                saveimageside(newphoto);
                              },
                              child: profileimage != ''
                                  ? CircleAvatar(
                                      backgroundImage:
                                          FileImage(File(profileimage)),
                                      radius:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                              0.05,
                                    )
                                  : CircleAvatar(
                                      backgroundImage: const AssetImage(
                                          'assets/profile1.png'),
                                      radius:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                              0.05,
                                    )),
```

Outside the build I have :

```
String profileimage = ''; 

 saveimageside(path) async {
    SharedPreferences saveimageside = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      saveimageside.setString("imagePathside", path);
    });
  }

  loadimageside() async {
    SharedPreferences saveimageside = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      profileimage = saveimageside.getString("imagePathside").toString();
    });
  }
```

called loadimagesside in initState
This code is not fully written by me but someone before me.

The blue container is replaced by default image only when I use remove profile picture feature which sets the path to '' Thats okay but I want the app to show default when user first installs it also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have checked if its empty but for example when you first opened the app without setting the path then loadimageSide() method is called which will get a null as a result and its saved in the variable profileImage. So now the value of profileImage is "null";

You can manage it when you get the image

```dart
loadimageside() async {
    SharedPreferences saveimageside = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      profileimage = saveimageside.getString("imagePathside") ?? "";
    });
  }
```

Now if the image is null then it will assign an empty string.